# ActiveMQ network of brokers connectivity scheme

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, cluster-computing

I need to scale up my ActiveMQ solution so I have defined a network of brokers.
I'm tring to figure out how to connect my producers and consumers to the cluster.

does each producer has to be connected to a single broker (with the failover uri for availability)? in this case how can I guarentry the distribution of traffic accross the brokers? do I need to configure the producers to connect each to a diffrent broker?

should I apply the same schema for the consumers?

This makes the application aware of the cluster topology, which I hope can be avoided by a discent cluster

Tx
Tomer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest you carefully read through the documentation from activemq.apache.org on clustering ActiveMQ. There are a lot of very helpful tips.

From what you have written I suggest you pay special attention to [this](http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html). At the bottom of the page it details how you can control from server side the failover/failback configuration for your producers.

For example:

> **updateClusterClients** - if true pass information to connected clients about changes in the topology of the broker cluster
>
> **rebalanceClusterClients** - if true, connected clients will be asked to rebalance across a cluster of brokers when a new broker joins the network of brokers
>
> **updateURIsURL** - A URL (or path to a local file) to a text file containing a comma separated list of URIs to use for reconnect in the case of failure

In a production active system then I would think that making use of updateURIsURL would make it a lot less painful scaling out.

Comment: It seems that the updateClusterClients and rebalanceClusterClients are not working for me as you can see in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062352/ any help will be appritiated